# Akka.Net Async await behavior in Untyped Actor

Tags: c#, async-await, akka.net

I m using Akka.Net 1.4.1 in Windows 10 environment.

I m using async await tasks within Untyped actor and so far have not run into any issues. As expected, only the current message is processed until await for a task is completed within the OnReceive method. No parallel messaging processing for the same actor begins until one message is completely handled.
However, I could not find this as a documented behavior. Most of the posts talk about using ReceiveAsync to have this behavior.

Can anyone confirm the behavior of using Async/Await inside OnReceive method of Untyped Actors in post Akka.Net 1.4.1 version?

Answer (score 3):

According to my understanding the [OnReceive](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/blob/0948525ff24f68fa939142f9d41f59744c0cd2ff/src/core/Akka/Actor/UntypedActor.cs#L53) is not designed for async processing.

If you look at the signature of the method itself:

```
void OnReceive(object message)
```

then it returns with a `void` rather than with a `Task`.

On the other hand [ReceiveAsync](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/blob/0948525ff24f68fa939142f9d41f59744c0cd2ff/src/core/Akka/Actor/Dsl/Act.cs#L71) does receive and async handler:

```
void ReceiveAsync<T>(Func<T, IActorContext, Task> handler, Predicate<T> shouldHandle = null);
```

For further information please check [this article](https://www.syncfusion.com/ebooks/akka_net_succinctly/working-with-actors).